# css: hidden overflow-x and magic mouse/gesture

Tags: css, overflow, swipe-gesture

I try to prevent the users from scrolling horizontally (asked by the client for a web app). This is easy with a "overflow-x:hidden" style.
In fact, it works as there is no visible horizontal scrollbar anymore.

The problem is that the magic mouse of Apple still allows the user to swipe the page horizontally in Safari Mac, Chrome Mac and Opera Mac (while he can't in Firefox Mac), even though the scrollbar is hidden.

I believe there is no need to show you the CSS as...it "technically" works: the scollbar is hidden alright.

But the swipe gesture with the magic Mouse ruins it as the user can still move the page on the left/right direction.

Any workaround, css, javascript or jQuery script to disable the horizontal swipe with the Magic Mouse or gesture?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `-webkit-overflow-scroll:touch`

Comment: I googled your css attribute and it returned nothing. Where do I put that exactly? I tried with the body tag with no success. Can you tell me more about this? Thank you!

Comment: I found this instead but even, it stills swipes horizontally when applied to the body:  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch

Comment: ive used before for mobile, but after re-read your question it is not related. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C12UKh85qi4

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found so far:

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (deltaX != 0){event.preventDefault();}
});
```

Don't know if I may encounter some side effects but so far so good.

It only targets the mouse swipe, not the gestures but I believe these are two different things as it appears that the mouse swipe is interpreted as a mouse move only, not as a gesture.

Comment: One downside of this approach, is that when zoomed in, horizontal scrolling is also not possible.